# $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{dt}{3+aSin[t]}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Considering the following integral with the method of residues
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{dt}{3+aSin[t]}$$ 
$$a\in \mathbb{R}$$
$$|a|<3$$

$$Sin[t]=\frac{z^2-1}{2iz}$$
$$dt=-i\frac{dz}{z}$$

$$\oint_{\gamma }\frac{2}{(z+\frac{3i+(\sqrt{a^2-9}{a})}{a})(z+\frac{3i-(\sqrt{a^2-9})}{a})}$$

$$\left | \frac{-3i-\sqrt{a^2-9}}{a} \right |>1$$
$$I=2\pi i Res\left [ f,\frac{-3i+\sqrt{a^2-9}}{a} \right ]=\frac{2\pi ia}{\sqrt{a^{2}-9}}$$
Surely this result is not ok because it must be real.
The correct result is $$\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{9-a^{2}}}$$
I can't find my mistake. 
Thank a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your result is real since $\sqrt{a^2-9} = i \sqrt{9-a^2}$.

And I bet your extra $a$ comes from the fact you forget the leading coefficient $a$ in your factorization.

Answer (score 0):

With $x=\frac\pi2-t$ :

$$I=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{dt}{3+a\sin(t)}=\int_{-3\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{3+a\cos(x)}=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{3+a\cos(x)}$$

the last equality resulting from the $2\pi-$periodicity of the integrand.

Now a parity argument leads to :

$$I=2\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{3+a\cos(x)}$$

With $\tau=\tan\left(\frac x2\right)$, we get :

$$I=2\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\frac{2\,d\tau}{1+\tau^2}}{3+\frac{a(1-\tau^2)}{1+\tau^2}}=4\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{d\tau}{3(1+\tau^2)+a(1-\tau^2)}$$

that is :

$$I=4\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{d\tau}{(3-a)\tau^2+(3+a)}=\frac{4}{3-a}\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{d\tau}{\tau^2+\frac{3+a}{3-a}}$$

We know that a primitive of $\tau\mapsto\frac{1}{\tau^2+K}$ (with $K>0$) is $\tau\mapsto\frac{1}{\sqrt K}\arctan\left(\frac{\tau}{\sqrt K}\right)$. Hence :

$$I=\frac{4}{3-a}\sqrt{\frac{3-a}{3+a}}\frac{\pi}{2}=\boxed{\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{9-a^2}}}$$